# Какие CORS заголовки должны быть для корректной работы amp-form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, form, amp

Осваиваю AMP, застрял на отправке данных из формы в метод.
Получаю ошибку:

```
Error: Form submission failed:: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​
```

Во первых правильно ли я вообще пытаюсь добавить headers

```
def create
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
  response.headers["AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"] = "https://m.spb.test.ru:3000"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"] = "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"
....
end
```

А во вторых не доходит, что там должно быть. То что выше не работает. Ссылка до метода выглядит так: `https://m.spb.test.ru:3000/records.json`

Метод то срабатывает, и в бд данные пишутся, но эта ошибка очень смущает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не понял, почему это не работало.
Оставил вначале метода:

```
response.headers["AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"] = request.protocol + request.host_with_port
```

Отсутствие остальных загловков ошибок не вызывают.